# How do you document React functional components using TypeDoc?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typedoc

I am learning through the React functional components and using TypeDoc to generate some documentation (maybe I shouldn't be using that).  Anyway I want to somehow get a list of states (or even states used) in the documentation that is generates without repeating myself in the top part of the function.

I don't think it is possible from looking at the code I have written since it's basically inner comments rather than something exposed.

```
/**
 * I don't want to document whatever states here...
 */
const AuthProvider = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactChild }) => {
  /**
   * OAuth token.
   */
  const [authToken, setAuthToken] = useState<OAuthToken | null>(null);

  /**
   * This state contains the AxiosResponse for the error or null.
   */
  const [authError, setAuthError] = useState<AxiosResponse | null>(null);
```

What I am hoping for is some sort of documentation like

### AuthProvider

I don't want to document whatever states here...

#### State Hooks

- `authToken` (mutator `setAuthToken()` )

  > OAuth token
- `authError` (mutator `setAuthError()` )

  > This state contains the AxiosResponse for the error or null.

Comment: How does the consumer access the inner constructs that you want to document?

Comment: Yah that's what I noted in ny OP.  I don't think it is possible.

Comment: I was asking a question. If you show an example of how someone uses the code it might be easier to see how to document it

Comment: TypeDoc maintainer here - This isn't currently possible, and I don't really understand why you would want to do this. These are purely internal details... outside of this function, they are completely inaccessible.

Comment: I sometimes want to know how the internals work, Javadoc allows for documenting private methods.

Comment: You'll either need a custom plugin, or some other tool, this is outside of typedoc proper's goals.

Comment: Agreed.  This is something more ReactJS specific.  I guess the one way around this is to use "class components" like the good old days before functional components.

Comment: Or use VueJS though I don't know how well TypeDoc works with VueJS vue component typescripts.